# How can I compile and distribute a Torque2D game as an executable?

Tags: torque-x

Is it possible to compile a Torque2D into a executable rather than having to run Torque2D.exe from the project folder (where all the `modules` and  `artwork` are)?

What would be the normal procedure to distribute a game written with Torque2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the Torque2D executable IS the game and the rest of the files including all your script files are just resources that the game loads when it runs.  To make the executable look like your game with it's own icon and name you'll need to compile the executable yourself after changing the name of the executable and the icon.  Even after doing this the script files will still be separate from the executable.  Before you release your game you should also remove all the .cs files and just leave the compiled .cs.dso files.